# Draining Dehumidifier through window

Tags: drain, drainage, dehumidifier, condensate

We are getting a dehumidifier for our basement and attaching it to a condensate pump. We would like to drain it out the window, but we want to know how to do that without having the window needing to be cracked all the time, as we don’t want little critters crawling in. What’s the best method for draining through a window?

Comment: An inside photo of the window and surrounding area would be helpful. You can click EDIT under your question, then use the mountain icon to add a photo. If bright light from the window makes the frame too dark to see clearly, block the window outside with a sheet of cardboard or similar.

Comment: **Drill a hole in the wall.** Or drill a hole in the window, thus making the window inoperable, because there's a pipe sticking through it. Which is why the correct answer is to drill a hole through the wall, not run a pipe through a window.

Comment: What kind of window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take a SWAG: You can drill a hole above the sill plate between the joists through an outside wall. Then insert a piece of tubing that will snugly fit into the hole or a piece of flexible metal pipe. Be sure the outlet points down about a forty five degree angle so the water will be away from the foundation. You can carefully calk where the tube comes out and connect the other end to the pump outlet. In my case I ran it to a drain, made it easy and Ino longer have to add water to keep it from passing out gas.

Comment: I would imagine there is a floor drain or drain pipes where it will be easier than going though a wall/window.

Comment: Thank you, Gil! 
And crip659, there is no floor drain (dirt floor that we’re getting redone as well) so that’s not an option.

Comment: @Mel if laundry is in the basement, you can drain through the utility sink also. Maybe even the standing pipe for the washing machine.

Comment: Yeah, there's gotta be a drain of *some* sort in the basement that you can attach a condensate drain to!